# Prevent linebreak between components?

Tags: java, html, jsf

How can I prevent linebreak in the following?

```
<h1><h:outputText value="sometext" style="text-align: left"/></h1>
<h:commandButton value="sometext style="text-align: right" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to put into context (maybe a small picture showing what you want to achieve?). Otherwise, try float instead of text-align.

```
style="float: left"
style="float: right"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1><h:outputText value="sometext" style="text-align: left"/>
<h:commandButton value="sometext style="text-align: right" /></h1>
```

H1 is a block level element, unless otherwise defined in the styles.

---

Also note you are missing a closing ".  It should be..

```
<h1><h:outputText value="sometext" style="text-align: left"/>
<h:commandButton value="sometext" style="text-align: right" /></h1>
```

Don't be afraid to try a [validation service](http://validator.w3.org/), they don't bite.